# Read a value from an Azure Keyvault from my local machine

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault, permission-denied

I am unsure how to authenticate against an Azure keyvault from my local machine.
While I understand I would probably never want to do that in a production scenario, I do want to do it for testing its use prior to production.

Is that possible?

While I did see [several options](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-identity/1.2.0/azure.identity.html#azure.identity.UsernamePasswordCredential), I failed to use DefaultAzureCredential and also CertificateCredential, ClientSecretCredential which I tried later, each with his own error, which I didn't completely understand.

The default one told me that:
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (Forbidden) The user, group or application 'appid=a79ae17f-90f7-4341-a2f7-b4ae4abad7d2;oid=cb8a8745-1567-4cd7-b8a0-5cecd6afe6c6;iss=https://sts.windows.net/98d1d263-cc4b-4d75-96a6-daf642242d3b/' does not have secrets get permission on key vault 'AnotherKV2;location=eastus'

**azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (Forbidden) The user, group or application 'appid={MYAPPID};oid={SomeOID};iss=https://sts.windows.net/98d1d263-cc4b-4d75-96a6-daf642242d3b/' does not have secrets get permission on key vault '{MyKVName};location=eastus'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287**

Which is weird for two reasons:

1. Firstly, while I did define a SP with {MYAPPID} in my subscription, I don't recall ever using it in my local machine, so how did my local app have the same APPID as (I assumed was automatically generated) the one I got when I created the service principals with the command:
   az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "MyApp"
2. Secondly, looking at the access policy of my keyvault, it appears that {MYAPPID} is given permission to do right about everything

Am I missing something? Should it be done some other way? (Or not at all?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your code locally, `DefaultAzureCredential` automatically uses the service principal described by the environment variables named `AZURE_TENANT_ID`, `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`, and `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`.

So to use it, please [`Set environmental variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-python#set-environmental-variables) in the advanced setting locally first, just use the values of the AD App created by `az ad sp create-for-rbac`.

To access the keyvault secret, you need to add the service principal related to the AD App to the `Access policies` of your keyvault with correct secret permission `Get, List`.

**Note**: Make sure the service principal is in the same Azure AD tenant with your keyvault, when you add it, please search for the `APP ID/Client ID` directly, because two different apps can have the same name.

Then use the code below, it works for me.

```
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

client = SecretClient(vault_url="https://keyvaultname.vault.azure.net/", credential=credential)

retrieved_secret = client.get_secret("sec789")
print(retrieved_secret.value)
```

[image]

For more details, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-python